# how to convert data.frame to numeric/matrix AND create barplot from time series from a csv file

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe, time-series, bar-chart

I want to make a barplot of Snow Data. The data is stored in a .csv-File and has a date column and 12 Location columns with a SWE Value in integer.
In order to creat a barplot the datatype has to be either a vector or a matrix. So my question is how i can transform the file (data.frame) to a matrix and create a grouped barplot from it. X-axes should be "date", Y-axes "SWE [mm]"
My .csv-file looks like this:

```
Date     SB1 SB2 SB3 ...
1.1.2013 95  90  91  ...
1.2.2013 87  80  82  ...
1.3.2013 45  30  15  ...
1.4.2013 23  18  3   ...
```

so far I tried:

```
setwd("path")
swe = read.csv("name.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
swe$new = paste(swe$Date," ")
swe$new = strptime(swe$new, "%d.%m.%Y")
swe2 <- data.matrix(swe)
dimnames(swe2) <- NA
jpeg("swe_sb1.jpg")
barplot(swe2$Date, swe2$SWE_SB1, ..., beside = TRUE)
dev.off()
```

it gives me the error message:

```
> setwd("path")
> swe = read.csv("name.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
> swe$new = paste(swe$Date," ")
> swe$new = strptime(swe$new, "%d.%m.%Y")
> swe2 <- data.matrix(swe)
> dimnames(swe2) <- NA
Fehler in dimnames(swe2) <- NA : 'dimnames' muss eine Liste sein
> str(swe2)
num [1:4, 1:38] 2 1 3 4 119 117 87 118 54 35 ...
- attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
..$ : NULL
..$ : chr [1:38] "Date" "SWE_SB1" "SH_SB1" "SD_SB1" ...
> jpeg("swe_sb1.jpg")
> barplot(swe2$Date, swe2$SWE_SB1)
Fehler in swe2$Date : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
> dev.off()
jpeg:75:swe_all.jpg 
              2
```

any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

You're making this way harder than it is. R has great examples for all of it's functions, so `?barplot` might have been a better place to start.

Anyways, what you have is a matrix that you want to make a grouped boxplot from.  If you have a matrix like the example one you'd see by typing `VADeaths`:

```
Rural       Male Rural   Female     Urban Male   Urban Female
50-54       11.7         8.7        15.4         8.4
55-59       18.1         11.7       24.3         13.6
60-64       26.9         20.3       37.0         19.3
65-69       41.0         30.9       54.6         35.1
70-74       66.0         54.3       71.1         50.0
```

And you wanted to create a boxplot, you simply type `barplot(VADeaths,grouped=T)` and you end up with
[image: simple bar plot]

If you want to switch the x and y, all you have to do is `barplot(t(VADeaths),grouped=T)`, and you have:[image: transposed bar plot].  So all you have to do is read in your data using `read.csv` or whatever, transpose it and plot it!

Comment: this doesn't work with my data set since I have dates in it. I tried your function and got this error message:setwd("path")
x=read.csv("test.csv", header=TRUE, sep=";")
barplot(x,grouped=T)  -->  Error in barplot.default(x, grouped = T) : 
  'height' muss ein Vektor oder eine Matrix sein = engl. "height" must be a vector or a matrix

Answer (score 0):

`read.csv()` returns a *data.frame*, `barplot()` does not accept this class.

Use `as.matrix()` before plotting to turn your data in an accepted class: 
`x <-as.matrix(x)`